# Sphere animation

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, animation

I need to make an animation to visualize spherical coordinates. So,what I need is, when I increase r, it traces a radius r. Just to make it easier, it traces in z-axis. Then, when we increase angle phi from 0 to pi,it traces a semicircle. And at end if we increase angle theta from 0 to 2 pi, the semicircle makes one complete revolution to make a sphere. I tried few things with RevolutionPlot3D but it is not helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to `RevolutionPlot3D` the three curves and add another two surfaces.

```
With[{r0 = 1, φ0 = π/3}, 
 Show[ParametricPlot[{0, r}, {r, 0, r0}, PlotStyle -> Red],
  ParametricPlot[{r0*Cos[π/2 - φ], 
    r0*Sin[π/2 - φ]}, {φ, 0.01, φ0},
    PlotStyle -> Green],
  ParametricPlot[{r*Cos[π/2 - φ0], 
    r*Sin[π/2 - φ0]}, {r, 0.01, r0}, PlotStyle -> Blue]
  , PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Show[RevolutionPlot3D[{0, r}, {r, 0, r0}, {θ, 
    0, φ0}, 
   RevolutionAxis -> Evaluate@PadRight[Cross[AngleVector[.02]], 3], 
   PlotRange -> 1.2, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
  RevolutionPlot3D[{0, r}, {r, 0, r0}, {θ, 0, φ0}, 
   RevolutionAxis -> 
    Evaluate@PadRight[Cross[AngleVector[θ0]], 3], 
   PlotRange -> 1.2, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
  RevolutionPlot3D[{r0*Cos[π/2 - φ], 
    r0*Sin[π/2 - φ]}, {φ, 
    0, φ0}, {θ, 0.02, θ0}, 
   RevolutionAxis -> {0, 0, 1}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   PlotStyle -> Green, Mesh -> None], 
  RevolutionPlot3D[{r*Cos[π/2 - φ0], 
    r*Sin[π/2 - φ0]}, {r, 0, r0}, {θ, 
    0.02, θ0}, RevolutionAxis -> {0, 0, 1}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotStyle -> Blue]], {{r0, 0.02}, 
  0.02, 1}, {{φ0, 0.02}, .01, π}, {{θ0, 0.01}, 
  0.01, 2 π}]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) for this excellent solution. Out of curiosity, how can you create an animation from mathematica by using `Manipulate` and not `Animate`. Do you have a link or a quick answer?

Comment: @bmf Thanks! I  am using ScreenToGif here.  Althought we can `Export` the `Animate` or `Manipulate` to gif, but is always too large to send to the forum.

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you very much for this wonderful animation. This is exactly I was looking for.

Comment: @cvgmt many thanks for the tip. I'll keep it in mind :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following?

- 1. Using spherical coordinates

Solve the equation for the sphere

```
eqn = r^2 Sin[θ]^2 Cos[φ]^2 + 
    r^2 Sin[θ]^2 Sin[φ]^2 + (r Cos[θ])^2 == xx;
r = r /. Last@Solve[eqn, r]
```

and then plot using and [`SphericalPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html) with a [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Manipulate[
 SphericalPlot3D[r /. xx -> xx2, {θ, 0, yy2}, {φ, 0, zz2},
   PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}], {xx2, 0, 1}, {yy2,
   Pi/10, Pi}, {zz2, Pi/10, 2 Pi}]
```

> [image: s1]

- 2. Using cartesian coordinates

We can use [`RegionPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html)

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ≤ 1, {x, -1, xx2}, {y, -1, yy2}, {z, -1, zz2}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], {xx2, 0, 1}, {yy2, 0, 
  1}, {zz2, 0, 1}]
```

> [image: s2]